# Maven - NoSuchMethodError: void com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(boolean, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object)

Tags: java, maven, java-16

I'm facing an issue with Maven and Java 16.

### The Problem

When I'm trying to package my project with maven `mvn package`, I got this error:

```xml
[ERROR] Error executing Maven.
[ERROR] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
[ERROR] Caused by: Unable to load cache item
[ERROR] Caused by: Could not initialize class 
com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$MethodWrapper
```

Following the solution brought by [this website](https://www.mail-archive.com/pkg-java-maintainers@alioth-lists.debian.net/msg15686.html), I have modified the symlink:

Before modification

```sh
# ll /usr/share/maven/lib | grep guice
guice.jar -> ../../java/guice.jar
```

Application of the fix

```sh
# sudo ln -s --force ../../java/guice-4.2.1-no_aop.jar guice.jar
```

After modification

```sh
# ll /usr/share/maven/lib | grep guice
guice.jar -> ../../java/guice-4.2.1-no_aop.jar
```

However, this leads to a new error:

```
# mvn
---------------------------------------------------
constituent[0]: file:/usr/share/maven/conf/logging/
constituent[1]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-resolver-transport-wagon.jar
constituent[2]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-core-3.x.jar
constituent[3]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/guava.jar
constituent[4]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-compat-3.x.jar
constituent[5]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/guice.jar
constituent[6]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-repository-metadata-3.x.jar
constituent[7]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-slf4j-provider-3.x.jar
constituent[8]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/commons-io.jar
constituent[9]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/commons-cli.jar
constituent[10]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/jansi.jar
constituent[11]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-settings-3.x.jar
constituent[12]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/wagon-http-shaded.jar
constituent[13]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-model-3.x.jar
constituent[14]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-resolver-impl.jar
constituent[15]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/wagon-file.jar
constituent[16]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/sisu-inject.jar
constituent[17]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/commons-lang3.jar
constituent[18]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/plexus-interpolation.jar
constituent[19]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-model-builder-3.x.jar
constituent[20]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/cdi-api.jar
constituent[21]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-artifact-3.x.jar
constituent[22]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-resolver-api.jar
constituent[23]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/slf4j-api.jar
constituent[24]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/plexus-sec-dispatcher.jar
constituent[25]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/wagon-provider-api.jar
constituent[26]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-resolver-spi.jar
constituent[27]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-settings-builder-3.x.jar
constituent[28]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/plexus-component-annotations.jar
constituent[29]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/aopalliance.jar
constituent[30]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/plexus-utils.jar
constituent[31]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/javax.inject.jar
constituent[32]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-shared-utils.jar
constituent[33]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-resolver-provider-3.x.jar
constituent[34]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-resolver-connector-basic.jar
constituent[35]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-resolver-util.jar
constituent[36]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-embedder-3.x.jar
constituent[37]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-builder-support-3.x.jar
constituent[38]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/jsr250-api.jar
constituent[39]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-plugin-api-3.x.jar
constituent[40]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/jcl-over-slf4j.jar
constituent[41]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/plexus-cipher.jar
constituent[42]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/sisu-plexus.jar
---------------------------------------------------
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(boolean, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object)'
    at com.google.inject.Key.ensureRetainedAtRuntime(Key.java:341)
    at com.google.inject.Key.strategyFor(Key.java:335)
    at com.google.inject.Key.get(Key.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.ParameterKeys.<clinit>(ParameterKeys.java:28)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.DependencyAnalyzer.<init>(DependencyAnalyzer.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.ElementAnalyzer.<init>(ElementAnalyzer.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule.configure(WireModule.java:74)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:344)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:137)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:103)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:87)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:69)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.addPlexusInjector(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:481)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.<init>(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:206)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.container(MavenCli.java:636)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:282)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
```

The keyword here is `NoSuchMethodError` about the `com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(boolean, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object)` function, which seems to be missing.

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67831548/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-void-com-google-common-base-preconditions-checkarg) asked and answered by @Menghe, I have tried to reinstall maven, but it does not have fixed the problem.

### My Configuration

| Software | Version |
| --- | --- |
| Ubuntu | 20.04.1 |
| Java | 16.0.2 |
| Maven | 3.6.3 |

It is possible to get an advice ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Remove the Maven installation and download it from here: https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi. and make the installation. The problem is based on the changing version within the distros which repackage things like that which causes the issue. More or less all the files in the error output are without full version number like (maven-embedder-3.x.jar) which in the original package maven-embedder-3.6.1.jar instead... also I suppose that via "mvn --version" you wil not get an output like this:"Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)" ... in particular the hash is missing!

Comment: See the same here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67481742/296328

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the Maven installation of your distribution and download it from here:
https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi
and make the installation. The problem is based on the changing version within the distros (ubuntu or others) which repackage things like that which causes the issue.

More or less all the files in the error output are without full version number like (maven-embedder-3.x.jar) which is in the original package maven-embedder-3.6.1.jar instead.

I suppose that you will not get the same output via `mvn --version` like this:

```
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: /Users/khmarbaise/tools/maven
Java version: 11.0.11, vendor: AdoptOpenJDK, runtime: /Users/khmarbaise/.sdkman/candidates/java/11.0.11.hs-adpt
Default locale: en_GB, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.14.6", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

In particular you will not get the hash in parenthesis
(cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)

Update (20. April 2023): In the meantime better use a more revent version of Maven.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using grpc-netty-shaded use

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.devh</groupId>
  <artifactId>grpc-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
  <version>2.14.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```