# 'maven package' gives error when try to build java project

Tags: java, maven, java-8, maven-3, java-16

**I am tring to build my java project with maven by using `mvn package` or `mvn clean install` but I am getting this error:**

```
[ERROR] Error executing Maven.
[ERROR] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
[ERROR] Caused by: Unable to load cache item
[ERROR] Caused by: Could not initialize class com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$MethodWrapper
```

**The project is simple java project which is using java 8.**
**Also, I have a few java version on my computer. If I run `mvn -X` when maven uses java 16, I am getting this error:**

```
Apache Maven 3.6.3
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 16.0.2, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-16.0.2
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.11.0-25-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
[ERROR] Error executing Maven.
com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get (LocalCache.java:2205)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get (LocalCache.java:3951)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad (LocalCache.java:3955)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get (LocalCache.java:4870)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked (LocalCache.java:4876)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache.get (FailableCache.java:51)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.get (ConstructorInjectorStore.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.initialize (ConstructorBindingImpl.java:155)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.initializeBinding (InjectorImpl.java:581)
    at com.google.inject.internal.AbstractBindingProcessor$Processor$1.run (AbstractBindingProcessor.java:176)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProcessedBindingData.initializeBindings (ProcessedBindingData.java:49)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically (InternalInjectorCreator.java:122)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build (InternalInjectorCreator.java:106)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector (Guice.java:87)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector (Guice.java:69)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector (Guice.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.addPlexusInjector (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:481)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.<init> (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:206)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.container (MavenCli.java:636)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:282)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache.createEntry (LoadingCache.java:79)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache.get (LoadingCache.java:34)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get (AbstractClassGenerator.java:116)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.create (AbstractClassGenerator.java:291)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.create (FastClass.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BytecodeGen.newFastClassForMember (BytecodeGen.java:258)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BytecodeGen.newFastClassForMember (BytecodeGen.java:207)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.create (DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:49)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProxyFactory.create (ProxyFactory.java:156)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.createConstructor (ConstructorInjectorStore.java:92)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.access$000 (ConstructorInjectorStore.java:29)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore$1.create (ConstructorInjectorStore.java:37)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore$1.create (ConstructorInjectorStore.java:33)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache$1.load (FailableCache.java:40)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture (LocalCache.java:3540)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync (LocalCache.java:2321)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad (LocalCache.java:2284)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get (LocalCache.java:2199)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get (LocalCache.java:3951)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad (LocalCache.java:3955)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get (LocalCache.java:4870)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked (LocalCache.java:4876)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache.get (FailableCache.java:51)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.get (ConstructorInjectorStore.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.initialize (ConstructorBindingImpl.java:155)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.initializeBinding (InjectorImpl.java:581)
    at com.google.inject.internal.AbstractBindingProcessor$Processor$1.run (AbstractBindingProcessor.java:176)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProcessedBindingData.initializeBindings (ProcessedBindingData.java:49)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically (InternalInjectorCreator.java:122)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build (InternalInjectorCreator.java:106)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector (Guice.java:87)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector (Guice.java:69)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector (Guice.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.addPlexusInjector (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:481)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.<init> (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:206)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.container (MavenCli.java:636)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:282)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$MethodWrapper
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$DuplicatesPredicate.evaluate (DuplicatesPredicate.java:104)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$CollectionUtils.filter (CollectionUtils.java:52)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClassEmitter.<init> (FastClassEmitter.java:69)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.generateClass (FastClass.java:77)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate (DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.generate (AbstractClassGenerator.java:329)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply (AbstractClassGenerator.java:93)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply (AbstractClassGenerator.java:91)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache$2.call (LoadingCache.java:54)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:264)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache.createEntry (LoadingCache.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache.get (LoadingCache.java:34)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get (AbstractClassGenerator.java:116)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.create (AbstractClassGenerator.java:291)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.create (FastClass.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BytecodeGen.newFastClassForMember (BytecodeGen.java:258)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BytecodeGen.newFastClassForMember (BytecodeGen.java:207)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.create (DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:49)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProxyFactory.create (ProxyFactory.java:156)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.createConstructor (ConstructorInjectorStore.java:92)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.access$000 (ConstructorInjectorStore.java:29)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore$1.create (ConstructorInjectorStore.java:37)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore$1.create (ConstructorInjectorStore.java:33)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache$1.load (FailableCache.java:40)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture (LocalCache.java:3540)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync (LocalCache.java:2321)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad (LocalCache.java:2284)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get (LocalCache.java:2199)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get (LocalCache.java:3951)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad (LocalCache.java:3955)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get (LocalCache.java:4870)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked (LocalCache.java:4876)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache.get (FailableCache.java:51)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.get (ConstructorInjectorStore.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.initialize (ConstructorBindingImpl.java:155)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.initializeBinding (InjectorImpl.java:581)
    at com.google.inject.internal.AbstractBindingProcessor$Processor$1.run (AbstractBindingProcessor.java:176)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProcessedBindingData.initializeBindings (ProcessedBindingData.java:49)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically (InternalInjectorCreator.java:122)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build (InternalInjectorCreator.java:106)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector (Guice.java:87)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector (Guice.java:69)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector (Guice.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.addPlexusInjector (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:481)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.<init> (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:206)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.container (MavenCli.java:636)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:282)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
```

**If I change the version of java used by maven to version 1.8 I am getting this:**

```
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_292, vendor: Private Build, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.11.0-25-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
[DEBUG] Created new class realm maven.api
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm maven.api
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.annotation.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.annotation.security.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.enterprise.inject.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.enterprise.util.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.inject.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.artifact < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.classrealm < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.cli < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.configuration < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.exception < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.execution < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.execution.scope < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.lifecycle < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.model < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.monitor < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.plugin < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.profiles < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.project < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.reporting < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.rtinfo < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.settings < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.toolchain < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.usability < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.authentication < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.events < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.observers < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.proxy < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.resource < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.classworlds < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.component < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.configuration < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.container < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.context < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.lifecycle < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.logging < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.personality < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.Xpp3Dom < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParser < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlSerializer < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.artifact < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.collection < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.deployment < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.graph < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.impl < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.installation < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.metadata < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.resolution < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.spi < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.transfer < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.version < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.fusesource.jansi.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.event.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.helpers.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.spi.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG] Populating class realm maven.api
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[DEBUG] Message scheme: color
[DEBUG] Message styles: debug info warning error success failure strong mojo project
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from /usr/share/maven/conf/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from /home/emin/.m2/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading global toolchains from /usr/share/maven/conf/toolchains.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user toolchains from /home/emin/.m2/toolchains.xml
[DEBUG] Using local repository at /home/emin/.m2/repository
[DEBUG] Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for /home/emin/.m2/repository
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project org.apache.maven:standalone-pom:pom:1: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecycle mappings for packaging pom from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.106 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-08-11T16:41:45+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.NoGoalSpecifiedException: No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:97)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoGoalSpecifiedException
```

**Also,**

```
emin@meb:~$ mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.6.3
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 11.0.11, vendor: Ubuntu, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.11.0-25-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

**Can someone explain me the reason.**

Comment: I suppose this is on a linux based platform where you have installed maven via the package manager of the OS? If so please remove the installation of the OS and install it from here: https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi (Just to be sure can you recheck: `mvn --version` what's exactly printed out?

Comment: ...also "No goals have been specified for this build" is where you have mostly not specified any on the command line, so would be great if you could share what command did you ran when you saw those logs? Something like `mvn -X package` and not just `mvn -X`.

Comment: @Naman That's not really a problem because even if you don't specify a goal / life cycle it should not fail with such kind of exeception.

Comment: @khmarbaise Just to clarify, I was talking about the second stack trace(requires code segment scrolling), that the OP got with Java-8 :) I am pretty sure, without specifying the goal that would be the experience, else I am willing to raise a bug on the JIRA maven project right away :P

Comment: @khmarbaise I edited ```mvn --version```'s output below the post. I am tring reinstall now.

Comment: That's what I feared. The reinstallation will not help. Download from maven.apache.org and download that and install it..remove the one from your OS....

Comment: @khmarbaise I am tring the do just like that

Comment: @khmarbaise It is worked,thak you so much but can you explain why it is worked?

Comment: All informations: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68593395/296328 detailed explanation https://stackoverflow.com/a/67482132/296328

Comment: @Naman The second part for the stack trace is simply a user problem (missing to give a goal or life cycle) apart from that I know really good about the Maven project because I'm one of the committers...  https://maven.apache.org/team.html#khmarbaise

Comment: @khmarbaise have been using maven for quite some time and I am well aware/thankful of that :)

Comment: Can you show your `pom.xml`?

Comment: @dan1st That is not the issue. See the comments before...

Comment: @khmarbaise I understand the difference, I am so thankful for your help.