# Springboot - An illegal reflective access operation has occurred

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I'm getting `An illegal reflective access operation has occurred` when trying to build. I've added `javax.xml.bind` as suggested by others but still I get the same error.

Any suggestion?

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1 (file:/usr/share/maven/lib/guice.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>demo-spring-boot</artifactId>
        <groupId>demo-spring-boot</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>baseapp/pom.xml</relativePath>    
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <artifactId>demo-web</artifactId>
    <groupId>demo-web</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <artifactId>demo-api</artifactId>
            <groupId>demo-api</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
          <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jasper-el</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: The Maven version you have installed (file:/usr/share/maven/lib/guice.jar) is **not** Apache Maven. It's an OS based package. Can you please try `mvn --version` and post what's the output...

Comment: Apache Maven 3.6.3
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 11.0.11, vendor: Ubuntu, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
Default locale: en, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.8.0-1038-aws", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

Comment: That's what I expected. Please download Apache Maven https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi and install it (also use a more recent version) and remove the version installed via OS. For detailed explanation please take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67481742/296328

Answer (score 1):

Your guice is incompatible with Java 11.

Comment: I've specified java 1.8 how come its using java 11?

Comment: <java.version>1.8</java.version>

Comment: Which version of guice supports java 11? any idea? I tried 4.2.2 but its still not working

Comment: @R0bert2 The problem is with the Java version used to run Maven, specifying the `java.version` in the POM only specifies that the class files produced need to be compatible with Java 8.