# Maven Build Profile Issue on Ubuntu WSL

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I was working in a spring boot project on a Ubuntu 20.04 installed in dual boot and everything was fine. Now I pulled the repo in a Ubuntu 20.04 running on WSL(windows 11) and now the project fails to build.
I build with the command: `mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring.profiles.active=dev`
The error is:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1 (file:/usr/share/maven/lib/guice.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------< com.robocup.olimpo:olimpo-api >--------------------
[INFO] Building olimpo-api 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.6.1:run (default-cli) > test-compile @ olimpo-api >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) @ olimpo-api ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ olimpo-api ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ olimpo-api ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/raicorreia/olimposystem/API/src/test/resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ olimpo-api ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.6.1:run (default-cli) < test-compile @ olimpo-api <<<
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.6.1:run (default-cli) @ olimpo-api ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.250 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-12-23T11:24:23-03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.6.1:run (default-cli) on project olimpo-api: Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.6.1:run for parameter profiles: Basic element 'profile' must not contain child elements -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginConfigurationException
```

What I think is causing this is the profiles configuration on pom.xml, which was fine in Ubuntu 20.04 fully installed and fails in WSL.
Apache Maven version: 3.6.3(on both)
Java JDK Version: 11.0.3(on normal ubuntu) and 11.0.13(on wsl ubuntu)

I wroten this pom.xml based on this tutorial, I don't know if there's a better way of doing it, to have 3 application.properties file for dev, test and prod https://www.baeldung.com/maven-profiles

Any idea why is this happening?

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <profiles>
                        <profile>
                            <id>dev</id>
                            <properties>
                                <activatedProperties>dev</activatedProperties>
                            </properties>
                            <activation>
                                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
                            </activation>
                        </profile>
                        <profile>
                            <id>test</id>
                            <properties>
                                <activatedProperties>test</activatedProperties>
                            </properties>
                        </profile>
                        <profile>
                            <id>prod</id>
                            <properties>
                                <activatedProperties>prod</activatedProperties>
                            </properties>
                        </profile>
                    </profiles>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: I'm not sure but isn't the version of the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` plugin different in both cases? Additionally, it looks like the `profiles` element can only accept a string (optionally delimiting multiple values by comma) whilst your `pom.xml` snippet looks like you've moved the Maven profiles section right into the plugin configuration which is illegal.

Comment: The issue looks like a problem with the Maven package in Ubuntu distro...  see https://stackoverflow.com/a/67482132/296328 second why are you combining Maven Profiles with spring boot profiles?

Comment: You should first check if your build is working without any issue on plain command line via `mvn clean package` afterwards I would check the issue warning about guice ....

Comment: The configuration for the profiles for spring-boot-maven-plugin is wrong: See details here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.6.2/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#goals-run-parameters-details-profiles

Comment: mvn clean package fails during test run i'll check your link, but this configuration is wrong but was working just fine outside wsl